# What was the extent of free speech under the Hellenistic empires?

Tags: classical-antiquity, hellenistic-greece, seleucid-empire

I have been doing independent research on censorship during the Hellenistic Period, particularly during the reins of the Seleucid and Ptolemaic Dynasties. So far the only example I can find of censorship is in the book of 1 Maccabees with Antiochus IV ordering the Torah to be burnt.

I’m aware of other periods in the ancient world where extreme censorship was the norm; e.g. during the Roman Period. I was wondering if free speech was just as restricted during the Hellenistic period as it was during the Roman period.

Comment: You may be looking at ancient societies through overly modern eyes. Anti-government speech among the wealthy and middle classes was certainly restricted at times even in the Roman Republic and Athens, but gossip, including political gossip, was universal and far beyond the government's control -- governments were small and disorganized by our standards. The more money you had, the closer you were watched and the greater the risk of denunciation by an informer hoping to get a slice of your wealth.

Comment: Thanks. When you say “gossip” do you mean spoken word, or written word as well?